Largest natural things by order of magnitude
Example of 5 largest natural things that are order of magnitude larger than second largest?
Note:

"natural" means they are on the Earth, and their size was not determined by humans
"order of magnitude" means largest is at least 5x larger than 2nd largest
"things" mean any category that is natural and can be compared by size
avoid using "subgroups" of some category, since cherry picking subgroups allow easier find
sizes in question should be reasonably confirmed, ie not speculative
examples are best put one per line, eg Category: largest name and size, 2nd largest name and size

Example:

River discharge volume: Amazon 209000 m3/s, Congo 41200 m3/s

I accidentally noticed one thing that fits into this list, and couldn't find almost any other (except Amazon above), so I thought it would be interesting question. Only couldn't decide if Puzzling or Earth Science, but it was easier for me to ask here.

I’m voting to close this question because it's a "big list" question with effectively unlimited answers, without any clear endpoint.

It is not "big list", it ask for 5 examples, one of which is already provided. And it is exactly interesting since there does NOT appear to exist "big" list.

Note that "order of magnitude" is here at least 5 times larger than 2nd largest while it is often described by 10 times.
Geography

 Largest lake by water volume
 1. Caspian Sea (Kazakhstan, Turkemistan, Azerbaijan, Russia and Iran), $78,200\text{km}^3$
 2. Superior (Canada and USA) $12,070\text{km}^3$
 Order of magnitude $\simeq 6.48$

Geology
Though geography is a tag of the puzzle and geology is not, I believe the following respects all the mentioned requirements

 Mass among underground arthropods
 1. H exapoda (inc. insects), $76\%$ of total mass
 2. C helicerata (inc. spiders and mites), $14\%$ of total mass.
 Order of magnitude $\simeq 5.4$


 
Source, American Committee and the Weizmann Institute of Science


Lake by volume is nice one ... i considered lakes area and they were not 5x different by that.   But "underground arthropods" rise one question: should we be allowed to cherry pick "subgroups"  category, like "underground" is subgroup of arthropods? because then it will be easier to find

Not only that,  top 2 underground arthropods are Ants at 4Mt and Termites at 3Mt - there is no x5 difference there. Only if we cherry pick "grouping" within subgroup ( like "exapoda","helicerata") we get x5.  But still interesting find.

These values are expressed as "how many times" one value is compared to another - you need a logarithm to convert to an order of magnitude. If you take 5x as one order of magnitude, an increase of 6.48x is 1.1 orders of magnitude - it's not 6.48 orders of magnitude. These values of 6.48 and 5.4 aren't orders of magnitude themselves, no matter how you define an order of magnitude.

Geography:

 Ice sheets by volume:


 1. Antarctic: 26,500,000 km^3


 2. Greenland: 2,900,000 km^3

Factor difference:

 9.14.


nice one ... i considered glaciers by size, but not entire ice sheets
